# issue with setValue on placeholder

Tags: angular, typescript

When a person writes age I am sending this value as a date (API is built like that).
I am using setValue for setting form value, When you submit a form it changes input the placeholder too, and I don't want that.
I want the placeholder not to change.
What am I doing wrong?

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-6xojcb?file=app/app.component.ts)

**.ts**

```
  onSubmit() {
    const birthDateValue = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("birthDate").value;
    const birthDateValueControl = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("birthDate");
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
    date.setFullYear(year);
    birthDateValueControl.setValue(date.toISOString());

    console.log(date.toISOString());
    console.log(this.formGroup.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row
birthDateValueControl.setValue(date.toISOString());

Is responsible of this behavior. If not necessary, delete it.

---Response
Ok, edit the onSubmit() method like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    const birthDateValue = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("birthDate").value;
    const birthDateValueControl = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("birthDate");
    // send age as date
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
    date.setFullYear(year);
    const finalDate = date.toISOString();

    console.log(date.toISOString());
    console.log(this.formGroup.value);
    const formArrayData = this.formGroup.get("formArray").value;
    const data = {birthDate: "1998-04-26T12:54:33.629Z"};
    console.log(data);
    // this.service.calculate(data).subscribe(
    //   (res:any)=>{
    //     console.log(res);
    //   },
    //   err => {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   }
    // );
    // }
  }
```

Comment: Hi i am sending that converted value to API and that's why is it necessary. when you type age and submit a form it changes placeholder. I want age that user types stayed but converted date I want to send to api

Comment: Ok, edit the onSubmit() method like this:

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder doesn't change in the example you provided, however I guess that you want to reset the form?
I think it's something like this.formGroup.get("formArray").reset() - In this way, you'll get your Placeholder back which is the word "Age".

Comment: Hi when you type age and submit a form it changes. I want age that user types stayed but converted date I want to send to api